# Why is db context used after destroying in this LINQ query?

Tags: c#, async-await, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have the following query and EF Core 2.2.6

```
public async Task<List<SamplePointContamination>> GetSamplePointsContaminationAsync(int siteId, int buildingId)
        {
            var siteZones = await administrationApiClient.GetAsync<List<BuildingZone>>($"sites/{siteId}/buildingZones",
                new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("IncludeBuildings", "True") });
            var buildingZoneIds = siteZones.Where(x => x.Building.Id == buildingId).Select(x => x.Id);
            if (!buildingZoneIds.Any())
                throw new SecurityException("Building does not belong to the site.");

            var timeFrom = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-9);
            using (var dbContext = CreateDbContext())
            {             
                //TODO optimize query. Generated sql does not promise
                return await dbContext.Analyses
                    .Where(x => buildingZoneIds.Contains(x.Sample.SamplePoint.BuildingZoneId) && x.CreatedAt >= timeFrom
                    && x.Sample.SamplePoint.Top.HasValue && x.Sample.SamplePoint.Left.HasValue)
                    .Include(x => x.Sample.SamplePoint)
                    .Include(x => x.AnalysisRisks)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.Risk)
                    .GroupBy(x => new
                    {
                        x.Sample.SamplePoint.Id,
                        x.Sample.SamplePoint.Name,
                        x.Sample.SamplePoint.Top,
                        x.Sample.SamplePoint.Left
                    })
                    .Select(x => new SamplePointContamination()
                    {
                        Id = x.Key.Id,
                        Name = x.Key.Name,
                        Top = x.Key.Top.Value,
                        Left = x.Key.Left.Value,
                        WaitingResults = x.Count(y => !y.ResultPositive.HasValue),
                        RiskTypes = x.SelectMany(y => y.AnalysisRisks)
                        .GroupBy(y => new { Id = (int)y.Risk.RiskType, Name = y.Risk.RiskType.ToString() })
                        .Select(y => new RiskTypeContamination() 
                            {
                                Id = y.Key.Id, 
                                Name = y.Key.Name,  
                                Positives = y.Count(z => z.Analysis.ResultPositive == true),
                                Negatives = y.Count(z => z.Analysis.ResultPositive == false),
                                IsPositive = y.Any(z => z.Analysis.ResultPositive == true)
                        }).ToList() //Crashes if ToList() is omitted. If using statement is removed, ToList() is not needed
                    })
                    .ToListAsync();
            }                       
        }
```

The first problem is that underlying SQL query is very inefficient because GROUP BY is almost never applied to the database (but done in memory) except in most simple cases, but this is not the topic.

The topic is that for some reason app crashes if ToList() is omitted (5th line from the end of code which is commented). Also, there is no error if I remove using statement. All my queries use this pattern with using and I never had a single problem until now. I know that I don't have to use using, but according to my opinion if used this way it should not make problems since I never try to access dbContext instance outside this scope. This error is showing:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: Cannot access a disposed object. A
> common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved
> from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same
> context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur is you
> are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a
> using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let
> the dependency injection container take care of disposing context
> instances. Object name: 'Context'.

So, obviously dbContext is used again after destroying, but I don't do that in my code explicitly. Obviously it has some connection with async/await and for some reasons adding mentioned ToList() solves the issue, but I have no clue what is happening and why the error exists without it.

Comment: The context is disposed at the end of `using`, but the query start with `ToListAsync` continue in the asynchronous  task.

Comment: Can you post a callstack of exception?

Comment: without `ToList()` `SamplePointContamination.RiskTypes` is `IQueryable` which is not "materialized" so accessing it will cause this exception (because it will query database)

Comment: my suggestion would be ether rewrite using proper joins or `ToListAsync ` the data and then work with in mem on the return data `var data = await dbContext.Analyses
                    .Where(x => buildingZoneIds.Contains(x.Sample.SamplePoint.BuildingZoneId) && x.CreatedAt >= timeFrom
                    && x.Sample.SamplePoint.Top.HasValue && x.Sample.SamplePoint.Left.HasValue)
                    .Include(x => x.Sample.SamplePoint)
                    .Include(x => x.AnalysisRisks)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.Risk).ToListAsync()`, and @Selvin is probably correct.

Comment: As I remember, in EF Core versions prior to 3 - EF can decide to evaluate any part of query on client, if it cannot translate it to proper database query. I'd suggest to start with turning this functionality completely off (for example as described here: https://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/ef-core-client-side-eval), because if EF cannot evaluate your query - it should throw exception. In this case most likely last select cannot be translated to query and so is evaluated on client, which is potentially very expensive and also leads to your problem.

Comment: @Selvin you are right, I just debugged it and tested. It does not crash until RiskType is accessed. I totally forgot about that. Thanks. And since it works also when remove ToList(), but also remove using, it seems that dbContext lives a bit longer and is able to be used on accessing time, but this also confuses me since dbContext is created locally, so its lifetime should end after exiting the function.

Comment: @Miloš, you have to do not use navigation properties after group by. Remember that. It may work (but i doubt) if you include all needed keys in grouping.